# Print passed value from url in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sinatra

This is my test.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

require  'json/pure'

get '/2015/:teachername/teaching/:subjectname' do

 content_type :json

 {

     "message" => "#{params[:teachername]} teaching #{params[:subjectname]}."   

 }.to_json

end
```

It's all fine, like when I access through url localhost:4567/2015/Anil/teaching/Sunil, but when I access this url in jquery I couldnot get passed :teachername and :subjectname.

Here is my test.html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>

  $.getJSON('/2015/:teachername/teaching/:subjectname', function(data) {

    alert(data.message);

  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to construct the URL string by appending your parameters in Javascript.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var teachername = 'Anil';
  var subjectname = 'Sunil';

  $.getJSON('/2015/'+teachername+'/teaching/'+subjectname, function(data) {
    alert(data.message);
  });
</script>
```